# While loop with function that asks for user input

Tags: bash

I got this function:

```
#!/bin/bash
prompt() {
read -r -p "${1:-Usunąć podany plik? [t/N]} " response
case "$response" in
    [tT][eE][sS]|[tT])
        true
        echo "Usuwam... $line"
        ;;
        *)
        false
        echo "Pomijam... $line"
        ;;
esac
}
```

And I want it to work inside a loop that reads line by line from a .txt file:

```
while IFS= read -r line
        do
            echo "$line" && prompt
        done < lista.txt
```

As I run the script here's the output (it doesn't actually prompt for user input):

```
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf
Pomijam... 11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI4.pdf
Pomijam... 11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI4.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI6.pdf
Pomijam... 11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI6.pdf
```

The lista.txt file looks like that if I use this loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line
        do
            echo "$line"
        done < lista.txt
```

Output:

```
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI2.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI3.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI4.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI5.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI6.pdf
11M /home/kamil/TEST/FOLDER ZE SPACJAMI/PLIK ZE SPACJAMI.pdf
```

My desire is that it prompts a user input as it reads every line.

Comment: Use a different `FD` at the outer `read` which is being done by the `while` loop.

Comment: `while read -ru9 line; do ....; done 9< lista.txt`

Comment: Thanks @Jetchisel it works to I'm learning bash at that ```-ru9``` is new to me.

Comment: see `help read`

Comment: I see that ```-u``` needs ```fd``` and ```9``` stands for that. I'm curiuos where can I get a information about meaning of that ```9``` :D

Comment: well `0`, `1` and `2` are taken already so `9` is just my lucky number :-), seriously `0` is `stdin` and `1` is `stdout` and `2` is `stder`

Comment: Is it related to ```/dev/fd```? Now I'm confused and I dunno where is that ```9``` from :D As for my ```/dev/fd``` I only got numbers from 0 to 5 (where 5 is a dir) o.O

Comment: See the `redirection`  section from `man bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you need to change is :

```
read -r -p "${1:-Usunąć podany plik? [t/N]} " response < /dev/tty
```

Comment: Thanks @Philippe that does the trick for me! Now I wonder what's the diffrence because when I'm trigering function alone it asks for input without that addon.

Comment: When you trigger function alone, `read` get inputs from standard input which is the same as /dev/tty. But when you put prompt inside while loop, `prompt.read` is also reading from the file. That's why you need to tell it to read from terminal, which is /dev/tty.